# Can I connect a keyboard Enter key with a Flutter onpress function

Tags: flutter

I have created a flutter web app where peoples log in. I have created a sign in page with only two fields for ID No and password and a Sign in button with a custom widget. Can I execute the sign in widget onpress function when the user press enter key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `onPress` what you can use is `onSubmitted` property of TextFormField.

As onSubmitted basically works when you press enter

Example:

```
TextFormField(
    controller: controller,
    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
       //This will fire when you press enter
        submitForm();
    },
 )
```